# Access asp.net web page from web site in web application using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have created new web application it's contains the index.aspx. another one web site is available. i have added the web application reference  into web site. now i want to access the index.aspx in web site using jquery ajax call . is it possible to access the same. thanks in advance all helps are appreciated.

thanks

Wood

Comment: The reference to the "Web Application" will give you access to the DLL (classes), but it's not going to give you access to the GUI/ASPX pages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're asking but if you just want to call your index.aspx page using jQuery from another website's page you simply do this:

```
$.get("http://www.mydomain.com/index.aspx", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  // do something with markup returned from your index.aspx
});
```

Hope this helps. You may try to clarify your question if this doesn't answer it.

Comment: it's not another domain. it's in same domain.. in visual studio i am create web application and i added the new file called index.aspx. next i create the new web site and added reference of the web application to web site. So i made the call to web site to access index.aspx . is it possible? are u get it?

Comment: 'http://www.mydomain.com' part of the URL should be replaced with the location where your 1st web application (containing index.aspx) is running. So if you're debugging and Visual Studio launches your 1st web application in a development server at location 'http://localhost:9308/index.aspx' then that is what you should use.

Comment: http://localhost:1667/WebSite1/handlertest.aspx this web sit url . i am able to access the site. i added the web application reference to web sit. it means  web application dll is added into web sit.  after that i access index page like http://localhost:1667/WebSite1/index.aspx it's showing error like The resource cannot be found.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here by adding the reference to another web application. Maybe you should describe what is the underlying goal behind what you're doing. The simple mechanics of accessing a page via a jQuery call should be solved by the code snippet above. Based on your comment, your index.aspx page can't even be accessed by simply browsing to it, so you should start there. This part has nothing to do with making an ajax call. You need to have a working page or webservice that you can browse to in the browser first.

Comment: i am developing one control not user control . that control should be use any application . like we will give the dll to developer . develope has added to there application and using jquery they need to access the page. that is my goal

Comment: I don't think you fully understand how this works. A Custom Server Control (which is what you seem to be creating) when distributed as a DLL is not a Page, its simply a control that will have to be used on a .aspx page or .ascx user control. It seems you want the developer consuming your Custom Server Control to be able to receive the rendering output of that control through a jQuery call. You can do that but your server control still has to be used on a .aspx page first and then that page can be called using jQuery.